# ClassExtensionContext can't be found in Junit 5 Jupiter version 5.4.0-RC1

Tags: junit5, junit-jupiter

Up to now I worked with Junit Jupiter 5.4.0-M1.
Now I want to upgrade to the version 5.4.0-RC1.

Unfortunately my program doesn't compile anymore because (among others) the class ClassExtensionContext couldn't be found anymore.

Does anyone know the reason or is there a documentation how to migrate from M1 to RC1?

Comment: Please open a bug report with more details here https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself:

ClassExtensionContext still exists but it is not public anymore.

I actually don't know why this has changed.
Anyway I had to implement a different check, whether an instance of the superclass  ExtensionContext is method or class related

Comment: `ClassExtensionContext` is an internal implementation detail of the JUnit Jupiter `TestEngine`. Consequently, you should never have had any kind of dependency on it.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you find that you "need" access to something internal in JUnit, you should open a GitHub issue to discuss the need.